# In C++ any other way for a function to change a variable in main()?

Tags: c++

Apologies if this topic has been rehashed a million times, but I was not able to find anything definitive elsewhere,... I was just wondering if there are any other ways a function can change a variable in main() other than by:

- Passing the variable by reference to the function
- Defining the variable as a global

In my case I have many identical sections in my C++ program that I would like to separate out into a function, however a big chunk of these sections are initializations of the form: < variable > = < some initial value >.
If I choose to pass all my variables by reference then I would have these very long function calls which I would like to avoid if possible,...
I could declare all these variables as global's and just call a function without parameters to change them, but then global variables should be avoided for other reasons,... I suppose I could also define a struct to hold all these variables and just pass a pointer to the struct to the function but semantically this seems strange because the variables are only loosely related,...

Is there no way I could define a local function that exists within the scope of main() to do this work? All I'm really looking for is a convenient way to reduce the redundancy in my program and make it more readable and
brief,...

With much appreciation,

Terry

Comment: Yes, return a value into it.

Comment: Pack them in a struct or tuple and pass the object by reference.

Comment: please paste an example, there are many ways of doing this.

Comment: If they are so loosely related, why are they all declared in main()?

Comment: A *global* variable is not a variable in `main`...

Comment: @Martin: Not sure this is the answer you were looking for (and perhaps this is a bad way of doing it but I'm still learning), but they are all declared in main() because it was easier to deal with epoll that way,... This is an app that runs across many processes so as is typical of epoll applications (from what I understand), I have one main 'network event processing loop' to deal with communication with worker processes and a 2nd 'non-network event processing loop'. I use variables to control the execution flow within each loop and across the loops so they all had to be declared in main().

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a lambda function. If you have a C++11 supporting compiler, you can do something like this:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    int i;
    double d;
    bool b;

    // The [&] part captures variables from the enclosing context by reference
    auto init_func = [&]() {
        i = 1;
        d = 2.0;
        b = false;
    }

    init_func();  // Initializes your variables
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using lambda functions just to initialize variables seems like a really bad example to me. And generally, it seems @Terry wanted to split up the program into functions for it to be structured better or have parts of it reusable, both of which you'd rather accomplish with normal functions (or OOP) than with lambdas.

Comment: @jPlatte I think lambdas are great for one-off situations. You have to use good judgement, but that's the case for every part of c++. In the end, it will depend on what Terry's program is doing, but I think it's good to be aware of the option.

Comment: Ok I have to admit,... this seems like a really elegant solution to my problem (if only I were using C++11!),... It would have certainly shortened my program, without the need to pass a gazillion variables, and made it more readable. It seems exactly like a locally defined function, a snippet of code that is reused,... However, since this is all new to me, I'm wondering,... why exactly is it such a bad idea to use this just for initializing variables (if I have a lot of them)? Note that I'm not just initializing variables in these repetitive sections in my code).

Comment: @jPlatte, so what is so wrong with using lambda's to initialize variables? (Not that that is the only thing I'm doing in these routines)

Comment: It makes the code longer for no reason. I mean, lambdas can be awesome to initialize variables, but not like this. What you can do with them what you couldn't do before when initializing variables could be for example to initialize a constant with a temporary (non-const) variable in a lambda, [like this](https://github.com/cyvasse-online/cyvasse-common/blob/master/include/cyvmath/hexagon.hpp#L280).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments: It depends on what the valiables are for.

Assuming they contain some configuration values I'd suggest to put them into one or a few structure(s) or class(es). In this assumption your values are related as all of them are configuration values (or maybe runtime states). In a class you also could add functions to initialize, read and write the config or synchronize read/write access if required.

Although it's close related to global variables (and thus there are many pros and cons), you can think about implementing a singleton pattern instead of passing the config object(s) to all variables.

Comment: I just knew that the 's' word was heading in the direction of this question:)